# User defined function call on a stack based interpreter for concatenative language

Tags: performance, c, recursion, functional-programming, interpreter

I would like to receive some advice on how to improve a small concatenative stack-based interpreter, executing a [joy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joy_(programming_language))-like programming language. It is really minimal, and is in fact a subset of a larger version that should, a priori, be used as a compilation target.

The version I would like to review here, however, is functional and representative of the other's base. In short, I would like to have global opinions on what should be improved or prohibited, and I would also like to draw more attention to the way the interpreter manages function calls:

```
void evalfunc(Stack *stack, struct Function *function, struct Dico *dico)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < function->body.size; i++)
        evalop(stack, &function->body.array[i], dico);
}
```

I actually have the impression that it's quite rudimentary as a way of doing things, and it doesn't allow you to recursion infinitely since it uses the program's stack; and as in this style of language, the notion of loop doesn't exist, there's only recursion, I wonder if there wasn't something you could do to allow a function like these:

```
undefined = undefined
forever   = doSomeStuff forever  // If we need to execute an entire program in an "infinite loop" for example, it would be really nice
```

not to cause a stack-overflow, even if the recursion limit is most of the time unreachable and sufficient. But, in a superset version of this project, programs to be interpreted will likely perform operations as we would with a simple `while(true)` loop, and recursion is the only way to do it now; I would not like to have to implement something that goes beyond the philosophy of concatenative functional programming... But if there is no other way to do it, let me know :)

So, here are the files and the makefile (using GCC, compiled under Windows with mingw):

**Makefile**

```
CC = gcc
CCFLAGS = -g -W -Wall -Wno-missing-braces -O2 -Wno-unused-value

OBJS = Combinator.o Function.o Interpret.o RawCode.o Stack.o Show.o

all : main

main : ${OBJS} main.o
    @echo Linking...
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} ${OBJS} main.o -o main

Stack.o : Stack.c
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c Stack.c

Combinator.o : Combinator.c
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c Combinator.c

Function.o : Function.c
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c Function.c

Interpret.o : Interpret.c
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c Interpret.c

RawCode.o : RawCode.c
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c RawCode.c

Show.o : Show.c
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c Show.c
```

**Combinator.h**

```
#pragma once

enum Combinator
    { POP, DUP, SWAP
    , FLIP, ID, QUOTE
    , UNQUOTE, UNKNOWN };

static const char Str_Combs[][8] =
    { "pop", "dup", "swap"
    , "flip", "id", "quote"
    , "unquote" };

enum Combinator string_to_comb(const char*);
```

**Combinator.c**

```
#include <string.h>
#include "Combinator.h"

enum Combinator string_to_comb(const char *s)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(Str_Combs) / sizeof(Str_Combs[0]); i++)
        if (!strcmp(Str_Combs[i], s))
            return (enum Combinator)i;
    return UNKNOWN;
}
```

**Function.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <ctype.h>

#include "RawCode.h"

struct Function
{
    char *name;
    RawCode body;
};

struct Dico
{
    struct Function *functions;
    size_t size;
    size_t used;
};

void init_dico(struct Dico *, size_t);
void push_dico(struct Dico *, struct Function);

struct Function make_Function(char *, RawCode);

struct Function *get_specific_function(char *, struct Dico *);
```

**Function.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "Function.h"
#include "RawCode.h"

void init_dico(struct Dico *dico, size_t size)
{
    dico->functions = (struct Function *)malloc(size * sizeof(struct Function));
    dico->used = 0;
    dico->size = size;
}

void push_dico(struct Dico *dico, struct Function function)
{
    if (dico->used == dico->size)
    {
        dico->size *= 2;
        dico->functions = (struct Function *)realloc(dico->functions, dico->size * sizeof(struct Function));
        if (dico->functions == NULL)
            perror("Out of vector memory");
    }
    dico->functions[dico->used++] = make_Function(function.name, function.body);
}

struct Function make_Function(char *name, RawCode body)
{
    return (struct Function){.name = name, .body = body};
}

struct Function *get_specific_function(char *name, struct Dico *dico)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dico->used; i++)
        if (!strcmp(dico->functions[i].name, name))
            return &dico->functions[i];
    return NULL;
}
```

**Interpret.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <ctype.h>

#include "Stack.h"
#include "RawCode.h"
#include "Combinator.h"
#include "LiteralOperation.h"
#include "Function.h"

// Execute the code from RawCode and return the resulting stack
Stack interpret(RawCode, struct Dico);
// Evaluate the given operation on the stack
void evalop(Stack *, struct Value *, struct Dico *);
// Evaluate the given combinator on the stack
void evalcomb(Stack *, enum Combinator, struct Dico *);
// Evalute a word on the stack
void evalword(Stack *, struct Dico *, char *);
// Evaluate a function on the stack
void evalfunc(Stack *, struct Function *, struct Dico *);
// Evalute the given literal operation on the stack
void evallo(Stack *, enum LiteralOperation, struct Dico *);
```

**Interpret.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "Interpret.h"
#include "RawCode.h"
#include "Function.h"
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Combinator.h"
#include "LiteralOperation.h"

#include "Show.h"

Stack interpret(RawCode rcode, struct Dico dico)
{

    Stack runtime_stack;
    init_stack(&runtime_stack, rcode.used);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < rcode.used; i++)
        evalop(&runtime_stack, &rcode.array[i], &dico);

    return runtime_stack;
}

void evalop(Stack *stack, struct Value *value, struct Dico *dico)
{
    switch (value->kind)
    {
        // If the value is a quotation or any literal, then just push it on the stack
    case Val_Quotation ... Val_String:
        push(stack, *value);
        break;
        // If this is a stack combinator, then apply it on the stack
    case Val_Combinator:
        evalcomb(stack, value->u.comb_.comb, dico);
        break;
        // If this is a "word" (a function), then evaluate it
    case Val_Word:
        evalword(stack, dico, value->u.word_.word);
        break;
    case Val_LiteralOperation:
        evallo(stack, value->u.literalOperation_.literalOperation, dico);
        break;
    case Val_Empty:
        printf("Empty stack!\n");
        break;
    }
}

void evalcomb(Stack *stack, enum Combinator comb, struct Dico *dico)
{
    switch (comb)
    {
    case POP:
        pop(stack);
        break;
    case DUP:
        push(stack, *top_ptr(stack));
        break;
    case SWAP:
    {
        struct Value tmp = *topx_ptr(stack, 1);
        *topx_ptr(stack, 1) = *topx_ptr(stack, 2);
        *topx_ptr(stack, 2) = tmp;
    }
    break;
    case FLIP:
    {
        struct Value tmp = *topx_ptr(stack, 1);
        *topx_ptr(stack, 1) = *topx_ptr(stack, 3);
        *topx_ptr(stack, 3) = tmp;
    }
    break;
    case ID:
        break;
    case QUOTE:
    {
        RawCode *quote = (RawCode *)malloc(sizeof(*quote));
        init_rcode(quote, 1);
        push_rcode(quote, *top_ptr(stack));
        *top_ptr(stack) = make_Val_Quotation(quote);
    }
    break;
    case UNQUOTE:
    {
        struct Value quote = drop(stack);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < quote.u.quote_.quote->used; i++)
            evalop(stack, &quote.u.quote_.quote->array[i], dico);
    }
    break;
    case UNKNOWN:
    default:
        printf("Unknown combinator '%d'\n", (int)comb);
    }
}

void evalfunc(Stack *stack, struct Function *function, struct Dico *dico)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < function->body.size; i++)
        evalop(stack, &function->body.array[i], dico);
}

void evalword(Stack *stack, struct Dico *dico, char *word)
{
    struct Function *tmptr_function = get_specific_function(word, dico);

    if (tmptr_function != NULL)
    {
        evalfunc(stack, tmptr_function, dico);
    }
    else if (!strcmp(word, "lowereq"))
    {
        // `x y lowereq` returns 1 or 0 depending on x is lower or equals to y
        evalcomb(stack, SWAP, dico);
        *top_ptr(stack) = make_Val_Integer((bool)(drop(stack).u.integer_.integer <= top(*stack).u.integer_.integer));
    }
    else if (!strcmp(word, "if"))
    {
        if ((bool)topx_ptr(stack, 3)->u.integer_.integer == true)
        {
            pop(stack);
            evalcomb(stack, SWAP, dico);
            pop(stack);
            evalcomb(stack, UNQUOTE, dico);
        }
        else
        {
            evalcomb(stack, SWAP, dico);
            pop(stack);
            evalcomb(stack, SWAP, dico);
            pop(stack);
            evalcomb(stack, UNQUOTE, dico);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unknown word '%s'\n", word);
    }
}

void evallo(Stack *stack, enum LiteralOperation lo, struct Dico *dico)
{
    // We have to swap the top of the stack for more logic:
    // `5 3 -`  will give 3 - 5 with the method below,
    // it's more logic for us to think that as `5 - 3`

    evalcomb(stack, SWAP, dico);

    switch (lo)
    {
    case ADD:
        push(stack, make_Val_Integer(drop(stack).u.integer_.integer + drop(stack).u.integer_.integer));
        break;
    case SUB:
        push(stack, make_Val_Integer(drop(stack).u.integer_.integer - drop(stack).u.integer_.integer));
        break;
    case MUL:
        push(stack, make_Val_Integer(drop(stack).u.integer_.integer * drop(stack).u.integer_.integer));
        break;
    case DIV:
        push(stack, make_Val_Integer(drop(stack).u.integer_.integer / drop(stack).u.integer_.integer));
        break;
    }
}
```

**LiteralOperation.h**

```
#pragma once

enum LiteralOperation
    { ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV };
```

**RawCode.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <ctype.h>

#include "Combinator.h"
#include "LiteralOperation.h"

typedef struct RawCode RawCode;
typedef enum Kind Kind;

struct Value {
    enum Kind
        { Val_Quotation, Val_Integer, Val_String, Val_Word, Val_LiteralOperation, Val_Combinator, Val_Empty } kind;
    union {
        // Quotation
        struct { RawCode* quote; } quote_;
        // Integer literal
        struct { int integer; } integer_;
        // Char literal
        struct { char character; } character_;
        // char* literal
        struct { char* string; } string_;
        // A stack combinator
        struct { enum Combinator comb; } comb_;
        // A word on the stack (a function)
        struct { char* word; } word_;
        // A literal operation (+, -, *, /)
        struct { enum LiteralOperation literalOperation; } literalOperation_;
    } u;
};

struct Value make_Val_Quotation(RawCode*);
struct Value make_Val_Integer(int);
struct Value make_Val_string(char*);
struct Value make_Val_Word(char*);
struct Value make_Val_LiteralOperation(enum LiteralOperation);
struct Value make_Val_Combinator(enum Combinator);

struct RawCode {
    struct Value* array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
};

void init_rcode(RawCode*, size_t);
void push_rcode(RawCode*, struct Value);
void pop_rcode(RawCode*);

struct Value drop_rcode(RawCode*);
struct Value top_rcode(RawCode);

// When the stack is empty
static const struct Value empty_value = { .kind = Val_Empty };
```

**RawCode.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "RawCode.h"
#include "Combinator.h"
#include "LiteralOperation.h"

struct Value make_Val_Quotation(RawCode *rcode)
{
    return (struct Value){.kind = Val_Quotation, .u = {.quote_ = rcode}};
}

struct Value make_Val_Integer(int x)
{
    return (struct Value){.kind = Val_Integer, .u = {.integer_ = x}};
}

struct Value make_Val_String(char *s)
{
    return (struct Value){.kind = Val_String, .u = {.string_ = s}};
}

struct Value make_Val_Word(char *s)
{
    return (struct Value){.kind = Val_Word, .u = {.word_ = s}};
}

struct Value make_Val_LiteralOperation(enum LiteralOperation lo)
{
    return (struct Value){.kind = Val_LiteralOperation, .u = {.literalOperation_ = lo}};
}

struct Value make_Val_Combinator(enum Combinator comb)
{
    return (struct Value){.kind = Val_Combinator, .u = {.comb_ = comb}};
}

void init_rcode(RawCode *rcode, size_t initSize)
{
    rcode->array = (struct Value *)malloc(initSize * sizeof(struct Value));
    rcode->used = 0;
    rcode->size = initSize;
}

void push_rcode(RawCode *rcode, struct Value item)
{
    if (rcode->used == rcode->size)
    {
        rcode->size *= 2;
        rcode->array = (struct Value *)realloc(rcode->array, rcode->size * sizeof(struct Value));
        if (rcode->array == NULL)
            perror("Out of raw code memory");
    }
    rcode->array[rcode->used++] = item;
}

void pop_rcode(RawCode *rcode)
{
    rcode->array[rcode->used--];
}

struct Value drop_rcode(RawCode *rcode)
{
    struct Value last = top_rcode(*rcode);
    pop_rcode(rcode);
    return last;
}

struct Value top_rcode(RawCode rcode)
{
    if (rcode.size == 0)
        return empty_value;
    return rcode.array[rcode.used - 1];
}
```

**Show.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Stack.h"
#include "RawCode.h"
#include "Combinator.h"

char* showStack(Stack);
char* showValue(struct Value);
char* showLo(enum LiteralOperation);
char* showQuote(RawCode);
char* showComb(enum Combinator);
```

**Show.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "Stack.h"
#include "Show.h"
#include "RawCode.h"
#include "Combinator.h"

char *showValue(struct Value value)
{
    char *result;
    switch (value.kind)
    {
    case Val_Integer:
        __mingw_asprintf(&result, "%d", value.u.integer_.integer);
        break;
    case Val_String:
        __mingw_asprintf(&result, "\"%s\"", value.u.string_.string);
        break;
    case Val_Word:
        __mingw_asprintf(&result, "%s", value.u.word_.word);
        break;
    case Val_Quotation:
        __mingw_asprintf(&result, "%s", showQuote(*value.u.quote_.quote));
        break;
    case Val_Combinator:
        __mingw_asprintf(&result, "%s", showComb(value.u.comb_.comb));
        break;
    case Val_Empty:
        return ""; // 'empty-stack
    case Val_LiteralOperation:
        __mingw_asprintf(&result, showLo(value.u.literalOperation_.literalOperation));
        break;
    default:
        return "'Unknown";
    }
    return result;
}

char *showComb(enum Combinator comb)
{
    return (char *)Str_Combs[(int)comb];
}

char *showLo(enum LiteralOperation lo)
{
    switch (lo)
    {
    case ADD:
        return "+";
    case SUB:
        return "-";
    case MUL:
        return "*";
    case DIV:
        return "/";
    }
    return "??";
}

char *showStack(Stack stack)
{
    char *result;
    __mingw_asprintf(&result, "[ ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < stack.used; i++)
    {
        if (stack.used >= 100 && i == 50)
        {
            i = stack.used - 1;
            __mingw_asprintf(&result, "%s (...) ", result);
        }
        __mingw_asprintf(&result, "%s%s ", result, showValue(stack.array[i]));
    }
    __mingw_asprintf(&result, "%s]", result);
    return result;
}

char *showQuote(RawCode rcode)
{
    if (rcode.used >= 50)
        return "[...]";
    char *result;
    __mingw_asprintf(&result, "[");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rcode.used; i++)
    {
        if (rcode.used >= 100 && i == 50)
        {
            i = rcode.used - 1;
            __mingw_asprintf(&result, "%s (...) ", result);
        }
        __mingw_asprintf(&result, "%s%s ", result, showValue(rcode.array[i]));
    }
    __mingw_asprintf(&result, "%s\b]", result);
    return result;
}
```

**Stack.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "RawCode.h"

typedef struct Stack
{
    struct Value *array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} Stack;

void init_stack(Stack *, size_t);
// Adds an item to the top of the stack
void push(Stack *, struct Value);
// Removes the most recently added item
void pop(Stack *);
// Removes the most recently added item and returns it
struct Value drop(Stack *);
// Gets the last added item => the top of the stack
struct Value top(Stack);

struct Value *top_ptr(Stack *);
struct Value *topx_ptr(Stack *, const size_t);
```

**Stack.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "Stack.h"

void init_stack(Stack *stack, const size_t initSize)
{
    stack->array = (struct Value *)malloc(initSize * sizeof(struct Value));
    stack->used = 0;
    stack->size = initSize;
}

void push(Stack *stack, const struct Value item)
{
    if (stack->used == stack->size)
    {
        stack->size *= 2;
        stack->array = (struct Value *)realloc(stack->array, stack->size * sizeof(struct Value));
        if (stack->array == NULL)
            perror("Out of stack memory");
    }
    stack->array[stack->used++] = item;
}

void pop(Stack *stack)
{
    stack->array[stack->used == 0 ? 0 : stack->used--];
}

struct Value drop(Stack *stack)
{
    struct Value last = top(*stack);
    pop(stack);
    return last;
}

struct Value top(const Stack stack)
{
    return stack.used == 0 ? empty_value : stack.array[stack.used - 1];
}

struct Value *top_ptr(Stack *stack)
{
    return &stack->array[stack->used - 1];
}

struct Value *topx_ptr(Stack *stack, const size_t x)
{
    return &stack->array[stack->used - x];
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "Interpret.h"
#include "RawCode.h"
#include "Function.h"
#include "Show.h"

// Define a function that just call itself
void _undefined(struct Dico *dico)
{
    RawCode body;
    init_rcode(&body, 1);
    push_rcode(&body, make_Val_Word("undefined"));

    push_dico(dico, make_Function("undefined", body));
}

// Define a function with a const value
void _const(struct Dico *dico)
{
    RawCode body;
    init_rcode(&body, 1);
    push_rcode(&body, make_Val_Integer(42));

    push_dico(dico, make_Function("const", body));
}

// Define the factorial function
void _fac(struct Dico *dico)
{
    // fac = dup 1 lowereq [pop 1] [dup -- fac *] if
    RawCode body;
    init_rcode(&body, 6);
    push_rcode(&body, make_Val_Combinator(DUP));
    push_rcode(&body, make_Val_Integer(1));
    push_rcode(&body, make_Val_Word("lowereq"));

    RawCode *if_true = (RawCode *)malloc(sizeof(*if_true));
    init_rcode(if_true, 2);
    push_rcode(if_true, make_Val_Combinator(POP));
    push_rcode(if_true, make_Val_Integer(1));

    RawCode *if_false = (RawCode *)malloc(sizeof(*if_false));
    init_rcode(if_false, 4);
    push_rcode(if_false, make_Val_Combinator(DUP));
    push_rcode(if_false, make_Val_Integer(1));
    push_rcode(if_false, make_Val_LiteralOperation(SUB));
    push_rcode(if_false, make_Val_Word("fac"));
    push_rcode(if_false, make_Val_LiteralOperation(MUL));

    push_rcode(&body, make_Val_Quotation(if_true));
    push_rcode(&body, make_Val_Quotation(if_false));
    push_rcode(&body, make_Val_Word("if"));

    push_dico(dico, make_Function("fac", body));
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Dico dico;
    RawCode rcode;

    init_dico(&dico, 1);
    init_rcode(&rcode, 1);

    _undefined(&dico);
    _fac(&dico);
    _const(&dico);

    push_rcode(&rcode, make_Val_Integer(4000));
    push_rcode(&rcode, make_Val_Word("fac"));

    // So now, the raw code is like     `5 fac`
    // The interpreter will interpret that and return 120

    Stack result = interpret(rcode, dico);

    printf("%s\n", showStack(result));

    return 0;
}
```

PS: I use a function specific to MINGW in the **Show.c** file, it is `__mingw_asprintf`. If there are compilation problems, it probably comes from there, so it has to be removed.

PPS: Here is [a link to download the files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/114i0fI8sKlTSY7h6Jej2zJCbxq7QhUWI/view?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Convenience `typedef`s

Consider adding convenience `typedef` declarations on your `struct`s and `enum`s, i.e.

```
struct Value {
   // ...
};
```

becomes

```
typedef struct ValueTag {
   // ...
} Value;
```

You've already done this with `Stack`, though I recommend renaming the tag:

```
typedef struct TagStack
{
    struct Value *array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} Stack;
```

### Uniformity of reference

```
struct Value top(const Stack stack)
```

should be

```
struct Value top(const Stack *stack)
```

since your other functions (correctly) accept pointers. Also, have a read through this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44157072/const-in-c-function-declaration-and-implementation

Your declaration and definition should agree on the `const`-ness of the argument.

### Makefile variables

This:

```
OBJS = Combinator.o Function.o Interpret.o RawCode.o Stack.o Show.o
```

shouldn't include `.o` in its members. For more flexibility, to get this list just use extension substitution, a la

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069457/how-to-change-the-extension-of-each-file-in-a-list-with-multiple-extensions-in-g#12071918

### Use auto-variables

in this:

```
main : ${OBJS} main.o
    @echo Linking...
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} ${OBJS} main.o -o main
```

you can instead do

```
main: main.o ${OBJS}
    @echo Linking...
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} $^ -o $@
```

Refer to https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html

### Object compilation

For these rules:

```
Stack.o : Stack.c
    ${CC} ${CCFLAGS} -c Stack.c
```

In the typical case you shouldn't even need to define them; make has a built-in extension-based rule for this. If you insist on defining it yourself, then you should use a pattern rule covering all of your objects at once; refer to

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html

### Memory span fragility

This:

```
if (dico->used == dico->size)
{
    dico->size *= 2;
```

is slightly fragile in an edge case: what if `used` exceeds `size`? Even if this "shouldn't usually happen", it's better to write it as if it could:

```
if (dico->used >= dico->size)
{
    dico->size = 2*dico->used;
```

Comment: Thanks for these tips; I didn't know the tips about makefile either, it makes life easier.
However, do you have any other ideas about my question on recursion about user-defined functions?

Answer (score 3):

## Use X-Macro to construct parallel enum and array

As the number of items increases, so does the effort required to keep the parallel constructions in sync.

```
enum Combinator
    { POP, DUP, SWAP
    , FLIP, ID, QUOTE
    , UNQUOTE, UNKNOWN };

static const char Str_Combs[][8] =
    { "pop", "dup", "swap"
    , "flip", "id", "quote"
    , "unquote" };
```

Instead, you can make a single list as a parameterized macro.

```
#define COMBINATORS(macro) \
  macro( POP, "pop" ), \
  macro( DUP, "dup" ), \
  macro( SWAP, "swap" ), \
  macro( FLIP, "flip" ) /* etc */

#define COMBINATOR_ENUM(a,b) a
enum Combinator { COMBINATORS(COMBINATOR_ENUM) };

#define COMBINATOR_STRING(a,b) b
static const char Str_Combs[][8] = { COMBINATORS(COMBINATOR_STRING) };
```

When you add more items, the enum and the array will always remain in sync. If you don't mind having the two parts in the same case, you could also simplify the table and use stringify to produce the string.

```
#define COMBINATORS(macro) \
  macro( POP ), \
  macro( DUP ), \
  macro( SWAP ), \
  macro( FLIP ) /* etc */

#define COMBINATOR_ENUM(a) a
enum Combinator { COMBINATORS(COMBINATOR_ENUM) };

#define COMBINATOR_STRING(a) #a
static const char Str_Combs[][8] = { COMBINATORS(COMBINATOR_STRING) };
```

This makes the list even easier to maintain.

## Loops and Recursion in the language

See [my answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949434/how-to-implement-loop-in-a-forth-like-language-interpreter-written-in-c) for implementing user functions with a stack. To allow for infinite loops or recursion, the important part is using a tail-recursion optimization. For stack based languages, the easy thing to do is pop the array when you get to the last element so the empty "tails" are no longer on the stack while you execute the last element.